# How to connect internal private DB2 to Cognos Dynamic Dashboard Embedded on IBM Cloud

Tags: jdbc, db2, ibm-cloud, cognos

Im working on cognos dashboard embedded using the reference from -
[Cognos Dashboard embedded](https://ibm-cognos-dashboard-demo.ng.bluemix.net/).

but instead of csv i'm working on JDBC data sources.
i'm trying to connect to JDBC data source as -

```
"module": {
    "xsd": "https://ibm.com/daas/module/1.0/module.xsd",
    "source": {
      "id": "StringID",
        "jdbc": {
            "jdbcUrl": "jdbcUrl: `jdbc:db2://DATABASE-HOST:50000/YOURDB`",
            "driverClassName": "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver",
            "schema": "DEFAULTSCHEMA"
        },
        "user": "user_name",
        "password": "password"
    },
    "table": {
      "name": "ROLE",
      "description": "description of the table for visual hints ",
      "column": [
        {
          "name": "ID",
          "description": "String",
          "datatype": "BIGINT",
          "nullable": false,
          "label": "ID",
          "usage": "identifier",
          "regularAggregate": "countDistinct",
        },
        {
          "name": "NAME",
          "description": "String",
          "datatype": "VARCHAR(100)",
          "nullable": true,
          "label": "Name",
          "usage": "identifier",
          "regularAggregate": "countDistinct"
        }
      ]
    },
    "label": "Module Name",
    "identifier": "moduleId"
}
```

Note - here my database is hosted on private network on not hosted on public IP address.

So when i add the above code to add datasources, then the data is not loading from my DB,
even though i mentioned correct user and password for jdbc connection  in above code then also when i drag and drop any field from data sources then it opens a pop up and which asks me for userID and Password.
and even after i filled userID and Password details again in popup i'm still unable to load the data.

Errors -

1 . when any module try to fetch data then calls API -
'https://dde-us-south.analytics.ibm.com/daas/v1/data?moduleUrl=%2Fda......'
but in my case this API is failing and giving the error - Status Code: 403 Forbidden

2. In [SignOnDialog.js](https://dde-us-south.analytics.ibm.com/daas/js/dashboard-analytics/lib/@waca/core-client/js/core-client/ui/content/dialog/SignOnDialog.js)
   At line - 98 call for saveDataSourceCredential method fails and it says saveDataSourceCredential is not a function.

Expectation -
It should not open a pop to asks for userID and password. and data will load directly just as it happens for database hosted on public IP domains.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work in general. If you are using any type of functionality hosted outside your network that needs to access an API or data on your private network, there needs to be some communication channel.

That channel could be established by setting up a VPN, using products like [IBM Secure Gateway](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/SecureGateway?topic=SecureGateway-about-sg) to create a client / server connection between the IBM Cloud and your Db2 host, or by even setting up a direct link between your company network and the (IBM) cloud.